# Refresh tableLayout using ViewPager (with Fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablelayout

I have a little problem

**Current situation**
I have a ViewPager with 2 Fragments inside.

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    if (viewPager != null) {
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

//////////////////////

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new PagerAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Frag1(), "Frag1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Frag2(), "Frag2");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

And I put it in my TabLayout

```
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

It works very well but now I want to change the fragments inside my tabs when I press a button in my navigation drawer.

**Here :**

```
     private void setupDrawerContent(final NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_menu1:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_menu2:

                    here for example

                    break;
                case R.id.nav_menu3:
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

How should I do this?
PS: I tried to add some `notifyDataSetChanged()` for the adapter.. `invalidate()` the tabLayout ... I removed the code because I did it wrong.

**Here is my PagerAdapter**

```
    static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter.